# Given probability distribution $f(x)=2-bx$ find $b$ and range for $x$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that the distances between houses and the center of a city are distributed with the density function: $f(x)=2-bx$, where $x$ denotes distance. If this is a proper density function, what can we infer about the value of $b$ and the range of values for $x$?

My attempt:

We know that $f(x)>0$ and $ \int_0^\infty f(x) dx = 1 $.
Finding the integral gives: $$ \int_0^\infty (2-bx) dx = b(-\infty)$$ which is no use in determining the value of $b$ or the right range for $x$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You are given that $f>0$ only on some range. Why do you see fit to integrate $f$ on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Because I didn't have any limit on x and I didn't see a way to find a suitable range.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[0,c]$ be the interval that $f$ is defined. Then
$$
\int_0^c (2-bx)dx =\left[2x-\frac{1}{2}bx^2\right]_0^c = 2c-\frac{1}{2}bc^2,
$$
and so $b=\dfrac{2(2c-1)}{c^2}$. $f(x)$ must be nonnegative, so $f(c)=2-bc$ must be nonnegative. Then
$$
2-bc=2-\dfrac{2(2c-1)}{c}=\frac{2}{c}-2 \ge 0,
$$
and so $0<c\le 1$.

For example, let $c=1$. If $x \ge 1$, $2-2x <0$, so you must integrate $2-2x$ from $0$ to $1$. Then
$$
\int_0^{1}(2-2x)dx=\left[2x-x^2\right]_0^{1}=1.
$$
That is, a probability density function $f$ is given by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2-2x,&0\le x \le 1\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
In general, $f$ is given by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2-\frac{2(2c-1)}{c^2}x,& 0\le x \le c\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Actually, any interval $(0,c)$ with $c\geqslant1$ supports the PDF $f_c:x\mapsto f_c(x)=(2-bx)\mathbf 1_{0<x<c}$, for $b=2(2c-1)/c^2$. Thus, the solution in this post, which is simply $f_1$, is far from being unique.

Comment: Oh, I misthought that $f(x)$ must end as 0. But is your argue right? Let $c=3$, then $f_3(x)=(2-\frac{10}{9}x)\mathbf{1}_{0<x<3}$ is not defined in $(9/5,3)$.

Comment: So is this only true for $0<c=<1$?

Comment: Yes, I think. And $b$ might be equal to or less than $2$.

Comment: Yes, $0<c\leqslant1$ and $b(c)=2(2c-1)/c^2$ hence $b(c)\leqslant b(1)=2$. To get $b(c)>0$, use $1/2<c\leqslant1$.